# How to Find the Cause of Too Many Dropped SSH Connections?

Tags: ssh, centos, logs

Overview: I have a home setup, behind a home router, on which there is Proxmox Hypervisor running over 10 VMs. One of those VMs is the first point of entry after router. It is just a jump host Centos 64bit. On the router all port 22 requests are forwarded to that VM. Then through that VM I control the rest of the VMs.

Problem: For the last 3 days I have been experiencing a high number of random SSH disconnects. Minutes after I ssh to the jump host or other VMs through the jump host, I get disconnected for no apparent reason. Sometimes it is after 20 minutes, sometimes 5. It seems like using vi makes it worse. I really cannot figure out what is causing it. The system is very stable most of the time.

Question: I started checking the logs. I don't see anything other than disconnect received and so on. So how exactly should I proceed to check for this issue? Should I check client side logs first? `/var/log/secure` on the jump host VM? logs on hypervisor level?

Answer (score 2):

This rather sound like a network or firewall related problem.

Are there any hardware-firewalls in front?
Do they drop connections after inactivity?

Try to activate the ssh-heartbeat - this might keep your ssh-sessions up and running.

Comment: i ll look into ssh-heartbeat. It disconnects while I am typing on command line so it is not the inactivity issue unfortunately. I found something on hypervisor level though. Proxmox is logging `proxmox kernel: vmbr0: port 11(tap110i0) entering disabled state` I m digging into that issue now...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured out the issue. Unfortunately after days of digging, it happened to be the cable. I have asked the person who runs the server in his home to check the cable and he said he did checked the cable and it was ok. But it wasn't...